# need jquery to change the default option of 2nd dropdown to "select" whenever i change options in 1st dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

This is the the jquery i am using. I am able to get "select" in district when i choose state but when i keep selecting different state again and again without touching district the values in district changes to the last option of each district. I want default to be "select"(disabled) each time i change state.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select3').selectmenu('disable');
    $("#select2").change(function() {
      if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
        $(this).data('options', $('#select3 option').clone());
      }
      var id = $(this).val();
      var option = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
      $('#select3').html(option);
      $('#select3').selectmenu('refresh');
      $('#select3').selectmenu('enable');
    });
  });
```

```
 <body>
          <label for="select2">State:</label>
          <select name="select2" id="select2">
                <option value = "0">Select</option>
                <option value = "1">Maharashtra</option>
                <option value = "2">Gujarat</option>
                <option value = "3">Rajasthan</option>
           </select>

        <label for="select3">District:</label>
        <select name="select3" id="select3">
               <option value = "0">Select State</option>
               <option value = "1">Select</option>
               <option value = "1">Pune</option>                       
               <option value = "1">Vidarbha</option>
               <option value = "1">Thane</option>
               <option value = "2">Select</option>
               <option value = "2">Bharuch</option>
               <option value = "2">Ahmedabad</option>
               <option value = "2">Jamnagar</option>
               <option value = "3">Select</option>
               <option value = "3">Jaipur</option>
               <option value = "3">Jodhpur</option>
               <option value = "3">Bikaner</option>
           </select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS alone to hide the other values on page load, and then filter through the select3 options. (You can't use your `$(this).data('options').filter` because `this` refers to #select2, not #select3, so the states options remain unchanged)

```js
const select2 = $("#select2");
select2.change(() => {
  const stateVal = select2.val();
  const select3Options = $('#select3').children();
  select3Options.show();
  select3Options.filter((_, elm) => elm.value && elm.value !== stateVal).hide();
  select3Options[0].selected = 'selected';
});
```

```css
#select3 > option:not([value="0"]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <label for="select2">State:</label>
  <select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option value = "0">Select</option>
    <option value = "1">Maharashtra</option>
    <option value = "2">Gujarat</option>
    <option value = "3">Rajasthan</option>
  </select>

  <label for="select3">District:</label>
  <select name="select3" id="select3">
    <option value = "0">Select State</option>
    <option value = "1">Pune</option>
    <option value = "1">Vidarbha</option>
    <option value = "1">Thane</option>
    <option value = "2">Bharuch</option>
    <option value = "2">Ahmedabad</option>
    <option value = "2">Jamnagar</option>
    <option value = "3">Jaipur</option>
    <option value = "3">Jodhpur</option>
    <option value = "3">Bikaner</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Comment: your code is working in the snippet but not working in the form which i made using jquery mobile. The select3 remains constant  when i change select2.

Comment: Still works for me when I use jquery mobile: https://jsfiddle.net/j7u4oj98/

Comment: It's because your jquery is getting in the way - none of the options are visible, as you can see when you Inspect, what you see there is in some separate `span` *above* the #select3. Select that span and change its textContent.

Comment: Im using $(document).ready so options are showing. But its not showing by window.onload. I can see the span above the #select3 but not sure what you mean by change its  textContent. How can it solve this problem.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#select3').previousElementSibling.textContent = 'Select';`